# Can I use GWT with handwritten HTML and CSS?

Tags: java, css, html, gwt

I'm starting work on a little HTML5 canvas game, and I was thinking GWT would be a great idea. I'd like to use Java, because 1. I have a lot of experience with it and 2. I would like to do it in an OO language. However, I read something about it being a pain to manage the HTML and CSS through GWT. So I was wondering, could I set up the canvas and style it using plain HTML+CSS, but then do everything else in GWT?

Comment: Maybe you are interested in https://github.com/ibaca/rxcanvas-gwt super simple canvas app or https://github.com/ibaca/pacman basic pacman game executable in JavaFX canvas (JVM) or HTML canvas (GWT).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use GWT to generate HTML or CSS.

I mostly use GWT with Ui:Binder, where the top-level element is HTMLPanel. Inside it, as much as possible is plain HTML and CSS. I try to keep project-level CSS in an outside .css file to ensure consistency, but you can pull as much CSS as necessary inside the Ui:Binder template.

Example of a Ui:Binder template, where I mix widgets (HTMLPanel, FlowPanel) with pure HTML. I use GWT widgets when I need some convenient functionality that they already provide, but you can deal with them as elements as well.

```
<ui:style>
    .empty {
        width: 100%;
        line-height: 96px;
        font-size: 16px;
        text-align: center;
    }
</ui:style> 

<g:HTMLPanel>

    <h2 class="sides">My Favorites</h2>

    <div ui:field="emptyLabel" class="{style.empty}" >You have no favorites at this time.</>

    <g:FlowPanel ui:field="container" addStyleNames="row flex-wrap" />

</g:HTMLPanel>
```

Comment: Would you happen to have an example project that uses handwritten HTML/CSS? I think being able to see the code wound help me understand it better.

Comment: I added a small example.

Comment: That's neat. Thanks!